# Chain rule proof. Why is $\Phi = f'(g(a))$ if $\Delta_h = 0$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

I was looking at the following link http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/A37W12/Chain.pdf to understand the chain rule proof, but I don't understand this part of equation (4):

$\Phi (h) = f'(g(a))$  if  $\Delta_h = 0$

Since we know that $\Delta_h = g(a+h)-g(a)$, if $\Delta_h = 0$ then $g(a + h) = g(a)$, so it seems to me that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(a)-g(a)}{h}=0$ since h is never 0.

This makes sense to me, since $g(a + h) = g(a)$ would mean that $f(g(a+h))=f(g(h))$ and therefore $f(a)$ is linear and therefore its derivative should be 0.

Where am I going wrong, and why is $\Phi = f'(g(a))$  if $\Delta_h = 0$

Comment: I think you mean $\Delta_h$ instead of $\Delta h$. The question is missing some details. What is the definition of $\Phi(h)$ for example?

Comment: You're right. I've changed it now. $\Phi (h)$ is defined in the proof at the following link. My question is about that proof in specific, so I think it wouldn't be appropriate to rewrite the whole proof here when it can be read if you follow the link, and instead only write the details of what I find tricky. I'm new to this site, however, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Where in the article does it say $\Delta_h = 0$? It says $\Delta_h \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$..

Comment: It does not say that $\Delta_h$ is zero, but in equation (4) it defines $\Phi (h)$ in terms of $\Delta_h$, and one of the branches is if $\Delta_h = 0$ then $\Phi (h) = f'(g(a))$, this is what I don't understand.

Comment: I'll write a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation $(4)$ says

$$\begin{align}
\Phi(h) &= \frac{f(g(a) + \Delta_h) - f(g(a))}{\Delta_h} \ \ \ \ \ \text {if $\Delta_h \ne 0$} \ \ (*) \\\\
&= f'(g(a)) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text {if $\Delta_h = 0$} \ \ (**)
\end{align}$$

The second part is just the definition of the limit. Recall

$$p'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{p(x + h) - p(x)}{h}$$

If we take the limit of $(*)$ as $\Delta_h \to 0$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta_h \to 0} \Phi(h) &= \lim_{\Delta_h \to 0} \frac{f(g(a) + \Delta_h) - f(g(a))}{\Delta_h} \\\\
&= f'(g(a)) \\\\
&= \Phi(h) \ \text {at $\Delta_h = 0$} \\\\
&= (**)
\end{align} $$

Which is what the text says.

Comment: But isn't a limit by definition only defined as it approaches a point but never on a point itself? I can sort of see how $\Phi (h) = f'(g(a))$ as $\Delta_h \to 0$, and even then, $lim_{h\to0} \neq lim_{\Delta_h \to 0}$, so the next step can't be valid, right?

Comment: But what I mean is that since $h$ and $\Delta_h$ could be tending at zero at different rates, how can you say that $\lim_{h \to 0} \Phi (h) = f'(g(a))$

Comment: Oh wait, my bad. This is answered in the third page. Thanks, I have accepted your answer. Edit: I think your answer was actually correct before, see page 3. Also, I can't upvote due to my low reputation.